# What is the significance of the names Mersault and Meursault?

Tags: french-language, name-significance, albert-camus, the-stranger, a-happy-death

The novel [*A Happy Death*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Happy_Death), written in the late 1930s and published posthumously in 1971, has a main character named Patrice **Mersault**. Camus's novel [*The Stranger*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stranger_(Camus_novel)), written a few years later and published in 1942, has a main character named **Meursault**. I was struck by the fact that these two characters in two different novels by the same author have *almost* identical names. It would've been less surprising if the names were completely identical, as a more obvious reflection of some relationship between the characters/stories; making them almost-but-not-quite identical just seems confusing for anyone who wants to read both stories.

**What is the significance of this?** Either the significance of either/both of the names themselves (do they mean something?) or the significance of the *difference* between them (that letter U) or the significance of their similarity (denoting very similar characters?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Camus loved the sea and nature generally. His unfinished early novel *La 
Mort heureuse* contains a scene in which Patrice Mersault goes swimming in 
the sea; the scene is described in very sensuous terms. (See [Albert 
Camus, La Mort heureuse, Le bain de 
mer](https://www.bacfrancais.com/bac_francais/168-camus-mort-heureuse-bain-de-mer.php), in French.)

So on a very literal level, Mersault can be read as *mer* (sea) and 
*sault*/[*saut*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/saut) (jump; the 'l' in 
'sault' is silent); when ignoring that French creates compounds in a 
very different way than English, the name can be read as "jump into the 
sea" (French equivalent: "saut à la mer").

After abandoning *La Mort heureuse*, Camus started working on 
*L'étranger*. He reused elements from *La Mort heureuse*, but 
obviously changed many other things, including the narrative 
perspective (the third person narrative was replaced with a 
first person narrative). The change from Mersault to Meursault leads to 
a name that actually already existed: 
[Meursault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meursault) is the name of a 
commune in France (now familiar to anyone who has watched the 1966 film [La Grande 
Vadrouille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Grande_Vadrouille)).

The change also introduces a wordplay: "meur" sounds like "meurs" and 
"meurt", which are singular forms of the present indicative of the verb 
[mourir](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mourir). From this point of 
view, Meursault "jumps" to his death by killing the Arab in the first 
part of the novel.

In *Looking for the Stranger* (University of Chicago Press, 2016), Alice Kaplan presents the following story about how the name change may have come about (page 65-66):

> In the only surviving manuscript of the novel, (...), Camus still 
>   spells his narrator's last name "Mersault", identical to the hero of *A 
>   Happy Death*. Later, he would differentiate him from the main character 
>   of *A Happy Death*, by adding the "u" to Meursault's name. When you 
>   pronounce "Meursault" without the "u", it sounds ethnically Spanish, 
>   like "Merso" (...).
>   (...) Some Camus experts claim he thought of the name change at a 
>   dinner party where he was served the delicious and expensive white 
>   Burgundy wine, Meursault. Whether or not the story about the Paris 
>   dinner party is true, there is something more expected about the way 
>   *Meur*-sault sounds to a French ear than *Mer*-sault, and the 
>   coincidence might have pleased Camus since the extra "u"—signifying 
>   *meur* (death)—served his novelistic purposes in every other way.

Comment: Thanks - I love wordplay. I assume "**Maur**-sault" is a typo in your quoted text, rather than yet another variant of this name? Alice Kaplan [also wrote about this on a blog](http://www.wondersandmarvels.com/2017/01/looking-for-the-stranger.html), with the interesting note that Meursault wine was awarded as a literary prize, so Camus might have chosen the character name as a joke hoping for nominative determinism in the prize.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. The story about the prize sounds strange, since Kaplan knows that *The Stranger* is set in Algeria, while Burgundy is in France.

Answer (score -2):

phonetically "Meursault" is the same as *meurt sot* meaning *dies stupid*. Quite fitting for both stories